# Django manage.py do not show commands of an app

Tags: django, django-1.4, django-manage.py, django-commands

I'm using Django 1.4 and have a project similar to the following:

```
project/
    __init__.py
    app1/
        __init__.py
        models.py
        views.py
        management/
            __init__.py
            commands/
                __init__.py
                ...many commands...
        test/
            __init__.py
            ...many tests...
    app2/
        __init__.py
        models.py
        management/
            __init__.py
            commands/
                __init__.py
                ...many commands...
        test/
            __init__.py
            ...many tests...
```

where `models.py` of `app2` is an empty file, and both `app1` and `app2` are listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`. The problem is that when i run

```
python manage.py --help
```

the commands of `app1` appears as:

```
[app1]
command1
command2
...
commandsn
```

but not those of `app2` as if there's no installed `app2`. And if try to run a command of `app2` named `app2command` it complains `Unknown command: 'app2command'`. But the tests for both apps can be run, in particular

```
python manage.py test app2
```

goes good. Is the problem the fact that `app2` has no models?

Comment: You don't need models, but you do (at least until 1.7) need an empty models.py file in your app. You do show it above, but can you confirm that you actually have one?

Comment: Yes, in `app2` there's `models.py` which is empty.

Answer (score 5):

I have just realized that I have a local settings which overrides `INSTALLED_APPS`. In `settings.py` the `INSTALLED_APPS` contains both `app1` and `app2` while in local settings `app2` was not there.